# Video streaming using RTSP: Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, wowza

I'm trying to install a Wowza server on my Linux machine to enable the RTSP streaming for my Android application.

On Android client side what sort of changes do I need to make in my application? I'm using Videoview to simply play a video file stored locally.

Now I want to get the video content get streamed through the server that I've installed. If necessary I can move to any other streaming server as right now I'm doing a research on streaming servers.

Comment: Hi pixel
Actually I' ve some different requirements. I m developing an android application for a site that provides content in form of music videos. I would play those video inside my application

Comment: @success_anil. Hi. Have you got any idea on streaming live rtsp video links. I am struck up here right now. Can you help me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For rtsp streaming you can also try following servers:

- **Darwin Streaming Server** - linux package is available
- **Windows Media Services** - can be installed on Windows Server Trial
- **VLC** - standalone application

For testing purposes of your application i would also recommend you to use existing mobile video services like:

- [m.youtube.tv](http://m.youtube.com)
- [m.wp.tv](http://m.wp.tv)

You can extract video links from those sites and use them to test your application.

Try to follow **Android ApiDemos**, you can find video streaming player example at:

```
 ...android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-x\samples\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\media\MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java
```

Comment: I am successfully able to play youtube links for rtsp streaming but I am not able to play live stream for rtsp URL such as this rtsp://122.166.229.151:1950/13479d885711433. This url is given to me by my client and it keeps changing. Can you guide as to why I am not able to play? Is it because it is not a file and is a URL?

Comment: @Rashmi.B were you able to play live stream , i am also stuck in this ?

Comment: @AmitHooda yes I did it

Comment: do u have a sample code for this that u can share with me? also can we achieve rtmp live streaming in android?

Comment: @rashmi how did you manage to play rtsp? Could you please share ur Knowledge?  I am also stuck :(

Comment: I used Daroon player to play rtsp streaming video

Comment: Daroon player is an outside player app it seems. How to play the IP camera live stream on another phone surface? Kindly post your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

VLC+Android Owns.

I used the following one-liner to stream video of our kittens to our cell phones.

We used the launchRTSP free app to leverage the built-in RTSP viewing capabilities of Android, to access the URL over the internet.

You may want to tweak the frame rate and such. As shown below, it's perfect for webcam streaming.

```
vlc -vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv -I dummy v4l2://:vdev=/dev/video:width=640:height=480:fps=2 --sout "#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,fps=5,vb=800,acodec=mpga,samplerate=8000,ab=64,deinterlace,channels=1,sfilter='mosaic:marq{marquee=%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S,size=16,color=16711680,position=5,opacity=64}'}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://0.0.0.0:5858/kittens.sdp}"
```

Comment: so this is VLC streaming the rtsp?

Answer (score 0):

[WCS4 server](http://flashphoner.com/wcs4) can deliver WebRTC stream as RTSP.

So you can send WebRTC live stream from Android or desktop Chrome/FF browser and then connnect to this stream via VLC or Android by RTSP.