# example for rtsp streaming in android

Tags: android, rtsp

Hi would someone post an example of how to stream audio/video files using rtsp in android........

Comment: See this question and the following answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186950/video-streaming-using-rtsp-android

Comment: excuse me , do you resolve the problem ? I have the same problem for RTSP server on android...

Answer (score 2):

Try this example :

[Video streaming using RTSP in android](http://jennifer-androidworld.blogspot.in/2011/07/video-streaming-using-rtsp-in-android.html?spref=bl)

Comment: This is not streaming at all. This is playback of a stream.