# Android play youtube video in webview

Tags: android, youtube, webview, android-webview

I want to play YouTube video in WebView or

When user click on youtube video I have to forward it to real YouTube app because in WebView I am not able to play YouTube video.

Is there any way to play a YouTube video in our WebView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play video in video view (the videos those are stored in local storage).

[Refer to this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android+play+video+file+in+android&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&source=www.google.com).

but if you want to stream it from server you have to go for rtsp video streaming.

[Look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186950/video-streaming-using-rtsp-android).

Comment: i want to play link clicked by user in youtube site. that's not at all playing in webview.

Comment: I've repaired the first link, but it is not clear what it is on that page you're drawing attention to. I wonder if the content has changed.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the video and device supports HTML5 you can do it through that, and if it has any flash elements you can run it as a flash application and it will treat it like a web page.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to ensure that you are able to view a YouTube video in your application.

1. Enable hardware acceleration in your application using `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`
2. Ensure that your WebView has plugins enabled
   `webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);`

If it still does not work, try loading the webpage a few times, or pass an Intent with the video link to YouTube.