# Android - playing RTSP audio streams using MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to creating radio application and one of the radio stations is using rtsp:\ protocol (rtsp:\\addres\file.sdp with mp4a codec). I was trying to play it using [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) but it doesn't want to work. Is it possible to play such audio stream using android with MediaPlayer or... other lib?

Any one :(?

Comment: Pls REFER this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186950/video-streaming-using-rtsp-android

Comment: But it is not answer for my problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Android supports for RTSP streaming. However, usually the Android Emulator have issued with playing audio or video streaming application. You should test your streaming application on real device