# RTMP client for android to publish video using wowza

Tags: java, android, rtmp, wowza

Now i am working on RTMP video streaming in android.please give some examples of RTMP client for video publishing in android.

Comment: Probably this link will help you. This allows you to publish android cam over RTMP.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123498/streaming-rtmp-stream-live-from-android-camera-to-fms-or-wowza-or-red5-convert

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest  [javacv](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) with ffmpeg.
I've tried different things and this was the only one worked. 
This [example](http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg/) will help you a lot, but you' ll need to do some changes and update libs.

If authentication is not required you can use flazr.

Answer (score 0):

try this library http://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/
This is a rtmp client lib ported from red5 and can be used in both android and other java platform. Compared to red5, this lib has a minimal lib dependency.

Comment: The link is not working. Please update it

Answer (score 0):

You should use Yasea or LibRestreaming.

Yasea can publish live video to your rtmp server (needs API 16+)

-Some devices , like MTK chips you can get 8-14 fps with yasea.

I also recommend LibRestreaming to you , if your target api is 18 and upper.

-You can get 20-30 fps with librestreaming

https://github.com/begeekmyfriend/yasea

https://github.com/lakeinchina/librestreaming

*I don't suggest javacv to publishing live video , because it takes up 10-15 mb in apk and works with slow fps*