# How to get a video stream from an RTMP server to Android?

Tags: android, stream, rtmp, justin.tv, twitch

I want to implement streaming from an [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) server. For example, below is the link of an RTMP server.

```
http://usher.justin.tv/find/CHANNELNAME.json?type=any
```

And want to do streaming of it.

I found one way: It is connected to a [SWF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF) file on a [Twitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitch_%28website%29) server (it is too slow) ... How do I convert it to VideoView from `rtmp://` to avoid using the Twitch API?

#### Answer after request:

[
{"node": "video10-2.arn01", "needed_info": "","play": "jtv_FO2coLXGNLzCXtvR","meta_game": "Diablo III: Reaper of Souls", "video_height": 720, "bitrate": 2915.1875, "broadcast_part": 5, "rank": 0, "persistent": "true", "cluster": "arn01", "token": "76b3d8aae0e6eee2bcda8d1acc34103f1a73b595:{\"swfDomains\": [\"justin.tv\", \"jtvx.com\", \"xarth.com\", \"twitchtv.com\", \"twitch.tv\", \"newjtv.com\", \"jtvnw.net\", \"wdtinc.com\", \"imapweather.com\", \"facebook.com\", \"starcrafting.com\"], \"streamName\": \"jtv_FO2coLXGNLzCXtvR\", \"expiration\": 1385121067, \"server\": \"video10-2.arn01\"}", `"connect": "rtmp://192.16.65.94/app"`, "broadcast_id": 7587457488, "type": "live", "display": "Source", "find_type": "dist"},
 {"node": "video12-1.fra01", "needed_info": "", "play": "jtv_LuAij7o0_zozQ4jY", "meta_game": "Diablo III: Reaper of Souls", "video_height": 720, "bitrate": 1600, "broadcast_part": 1, "rank": 1, "persistent": "true", "cluster": "fra01", "token": "b4db7f59d3b4d723624ee50ed2d69519d1a4cebb:{\"swfDomains\": [\"justin.tv\", \"jtvx.com\", \"xarth.com\", \"twitchtv.com\", \"twitch.tv\", \"newjtv.com\", \"jtvnw.net\", \"wdtinc.com\", \"imapweather.com\", \"facebook.com\", \"starcrafting.com\"], \"streamName\": \"jtv_LuAij7o0_zozQ4jY\", \"expiration\": 1385121067, \"server\": \"video12-1.fra01\"}", `"connect": "rtmp://199.9.254.232/app"`, "broadcast_id": 7587458496, "type": "high", "display": "High", "find_type": "dist"},
{"node": "video15-2.arn01", "needed_info": "", "play": "jtv_e38UUDs1WLMP9wlc", "meta_game": "Diablo III: Reaper of Souls", "video_height": 360, "bitrate": 350, "broadcast_part": 1, "rank": 3, "persistent": "true", "cluster": "arn01", "token": "c416673c070354e1a33edcdb535a195463cd9702:{\"swfDomains\": [\"justin.tv\", \"jtvx.com\", \"xarth.com\", \"twitchtv.com\", \"twitch.tv\", \"newjtv.com\", \"jtvnw.net\", \"wdtinc.com\", \"imapweather.com\", \"facebook.com\", \"starcrafting.com\"], \"streamName\": \"jtv_e38UUDs1WLMP9wlc\", \"expiration\": 1385121067, \"server\": \"video15-2.arn01\"}", `"connect": "rtmp://192.16.65.99/app"`, "broadcast_id": 7587458512, "type": "low", "display": "Low", "find_type": "dist"},
{"node": "video12-1.fra01", "needed_info": "", "play": "jtv_bRMbL_ROsoHAegM2", "meta_game": "Diablo III: Reaper of Souls", "video_height": 480, "bitrate": 800, "broadcast_part": 1, "rank": 2, "persistent": "true", "cluster": "fra01", "token": "bed50de10852dd0f7a24d687f43a10463557b5a3:{\"swfDomains\": [\"justin.tv\", \"jtvx.com\", \"xarth.com\", \"twitchtv.com\", \"twitch.tv\", \"newjtv.com\", \"jtvnw.net\", \"wdtinc.com\", \"imapweather.com\", \"facebook.com\", \"starcrafting.com\"], \"streamName\": \"jtv_bRMbL_ROsoHAegM2\", \"expiration\": 1385121067, \"server\": \"video12-1.fra01\"}", `"connect": "rtmp://199.9.254.232/app"`, "broadcast_id": 7587458528, "type": "medium", "display": "Medium", "find_type": "dist"}]

I found the best way for getting a stream on a PC: *[Watch twitch.tv/justin.tv/own3d.tv streams in VLC](http://jultech.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/watch-twitch-tvjustin-tvown3d-tv-streams-in-vlc/#comment-2325)*.

It uses this [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code: http://bog.no-ip.biz/sc2/stream2vlc.php

But I don't have any idea on how to implement it in an Android project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Adobe AIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime) SDK that can run on Android. It is very simple and can work with RTMP by default.

Comment: adobe air is a sdk and environment that can run on android and ios by writing action script code. I have not done that much with air, but quiet some things with the flash media server and streaming videos. it is very simple and the SDK keeps care of all. Very nice API documentation and code runs fast. Give it a try.

Comment: Can you provide some link or sample for acheving as you said?

Answer (score 0):

As WebView supports RTSP, perhaps you can convert the stream from RTMP to RTSP on the fly.

I didn't try this, but a websearch gave me this for example: *[RTMP To RTSP re-stream using wowza and xuggler](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/rtmp-to-rtsp-re-stream-using-wowza-and.html)*.