# Recording and watching video live streaming using red 5 and rtsp for android

Tags: android, ios, video

I have spent enough time searching for a solution but I am not sure which way I should go. That is why I am asking question here.
 I want to make an application from where I can record a video and same video will be shown live on any other device connected to the network or it can be on web using JWplayer or some thing like that.
Now I have done enough R&D and we are not considering WOwza server (as it is paid) . So on web side we have already implemented in which web cam in recording video and which can be seen on our web site and also on android and iphone browsers live.
But problem with red 5 is that is does not give support to RTSP (it only supports RTMP) unlike Wowza which handles RTSP internally and convert it into RTMP.
I have found few links who suggested client side RTMP handling what so far no success.

[Convert video Input Stream to RTMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123498/streaming-rtmp-stream-live-from-android-camera-to-fms-or-wowza-or-red5-convert) 
This links explains lot of things but I am not sure which way I should spend my time or it is possible to convert RTSP into RTMP for red 5 server.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.Broadcaster 
this guy has achieve this functionality I guess but we are looking for the native application.

Please suggest me in the right direction I should go and invest my time live record and watch video stream.

We can use other servers which are open source rather than red 5 , if it fulfill my needs on both iOS, android and web else I ll have to go with wowza which I dnt want for now.