# Android - Stream camera as RTMP stream

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtmp

I want to capture the camera stream from an Android device and stream it to a server with RTMP (the server is **out** of my control). I have not figured out yet how to create a stream of data from the camera itself, but that is for a later concern.

At the moment there are two problems: I wish to support API 9+ and RTMP is not native supported by Android.

I've taken a look around and found this SO post [Convert video Input Stream to RTMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123498/streaming-rtmp-stream-live-from-android-camera-to-fms-or-wowza-or-red5-convert) and https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle. The former suggested [a library](https://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/)  that has little to no documentation. The latter *probably* supports it (?), but it requires API 14+.

Are there decent examples or libraries out there, that that supports RTMP streaming from an Android device? I've also read something about converting RTSP or FFMPEG, if that is a viable way then I guess it will suffice too.

## Edit 1:

I've found [this library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtmpjavaclient/) (It has a lot of resemblance to the one mentioned above) and tried to work with. I imported it in Android Studio and wrote some code, but it appears to crash internally with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError RTSP Codec Factory` error. So apparently that doesn't work too well on Android.

Also, I've encountered several times Adobe air. I do not want to code in Action Script 3 (AS3) as this library will just be a (small) part of a native app. If Adobe Air has a library which I am unaware of, then I would happily integrate it if that is possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the [accepted answer of the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123498/streaming-rtmp-stream-live-from-android-camera-to-fms-or-wowza-or-red5-convert) someone suggests using JavaCV.

It requires API 8 or newer and features a **FFmpegFrameRecorder** class.

Link to github:

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

They even have a full sample of capturing flv (it's rather large so I won't paste it here):
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/RecordActivity.java

In your case you probably need to replace:

```
private String ffmpeg_link = "/mnt/sdcard/stream.flv";
```

with

```
private String ffmpeg_link = "rtmp://<server>:<port>/stream";
```

Comment: This looks promising. I tried the example but getting a ``java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`` caused by ``Couldn't load jniopencv_core: findLibrary returned null`` error.

Comment: Did you deploy all libs? Look around SO and Google Code (rip) because there are some related issues

Comment: It works for me with nginx rtmp server but it only streams a black video. I think it has codec issue. I'm using recorder.setVideoCodec() to set codec ...

Comment: finally I solved black video issue by setting RECORD_LENGTH = 0 in RecordActivity class.

Comment: I tried to sent RTMP stream to RED5 server and its work. The live stream is not getting stored in the RED5 server as flv file.  Do u have any idea about the changes to be done to store the stream in Red5 server. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you can publish from your android device using a protocol supported by ffmpeg (see [the list of protocols supported](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html)) you could use the following command to transmit the video to your server :

```
ffmpeg -re -i <input link> -vcodec h264 -ar 44100 -f flv "rtmp://<host>/<publication>"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? How would you run that command from inside an android app? This app should send a stream using RTMP to a server that is out of his control.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were the owner of the server. You could try this repository https://github.com/cine-io/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp but I don't know if it works well. Otherwise you could also develop an AIR application, it works!

Comment: I do not want to code in AS3, so I guess AIR will not do. Unless they have a library you can add?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at `spydroid`; it does exactly what you are looking for. Their website may be found here: https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/

They provide a library that you can use, along with an explanation of the various streaming options and some code examples. Said information may be found here: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

Comment: I will definitely take a look.

Comment: Are you sure this supports RTMP? I only find RT(S)P in the list (wiki). Or can you use these? I am new to streaming stuff, so I don't really know for sure.