# How to setup Live Streaming on Android app using AWS/GCP?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, live-streaming, ant-media-server-sdk

I'm developing an android app where user can start live streaming using his/her android-camera. I have `AWS` & `GCP` resources at hand. What I understand after some reading is,

1. I have to stream/publish, whatever android-camera is picking, to some server over some protocols(`RTMP` or `HLS`, etc..)
2. I have to setup server that will pull this input source and packages & stores it in a form that could be streamed/consumed on the mobile/web browser(Basically, an URL) and I believe `AWS's MediaLive`, `MediaPackage`, etc.. resources should do that.
3. I could use this URL are MediaSource for players on Android(like `ExoPlayer`)

My problem is I couldn't find good documentation on 1st part. I found this, https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv, which doesn't appear to be production-level work. While trying out 2nd part, while creating MediaLive channel on AWS, I was asked to point the channel to 2 destinations(I don't know what it means) which made me doubt my understanding of this process. I'm looking for some skeleton-procedure with official documentation on how to achieve this.

**EDIT 1:**

For the Input-Production part, I'm experimenting with this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29061628/3881561

**EDIT 2:**

I've used https://github.com/ant-media/LiveVideoBroadcaster to send video source to RTMP server. I've created RTMP push input source in MediaLive and a channel with output - Archive(stores .ts files in S3). Now that the flow is working, How can I modify this architecture to allow multiple users to create live streaming?

Comment: I suggest using a service that does this for you, like [mux.com](http://mux.com)

Comment: Setup would be like Android -->(rtmp/rtp/hls, input) Medialive(output hls/dash) --> Mediapackage --> Cloudfront, the setup is easy, medialive provides 2 endpoints but you can only use one if you choose rtp push or rtmp push. However, the main problem is how you're using to send rtmp/rtp stream from your android device  to medialive, simple camera won'r encode it for, you need some encoder to create rtmp/rtp stream for you and push it to medialive, the better option for you to use kinesis video streaming and use sdk to generate that stream for you.

Comment: @JamesDean 1. What does "Destination Name & Instance" mean, while creating Input for MediaLive?
2. Does this implementation work if more than 1 user tries to create Live Stream?

Comment: AWS SDK provides methods to createChannel and such that would allow you to create new channels for new users. What I would like to know is since those channels take a minute to "initialize," does that mean it will also cost money if there is no input feed pushing data into the channel? I would hate to create a new channel for a new user and get charged when they aren't streaming anything.