# Live video stream from android mobile to desktop web browser

Tags: php, android, html, browser, video-streaming

I have to develop an application that will record video and audio on desktop browser and android smartphone and share it between them. Just like the skype video call.

The application will consist of three subapplications on these three platforms:

- smartphone (android java)
- web server (apache + php)
- destkop web browser (html5 + javascript + css)

---

1. Could you recommend me any libraries that could help me on these platforms
   (smartphone, web server, web browser)?
2. Will I be able to maintain all the work on web server **just by**
   `php` (user logging, video streaming, ...)?
3. Will I be able to maintain video record and playback in web browser
   **just by** `html5` + `js` or **do I need** to use `flash`/`silverlight`?
4. What things will web server need to do? Just store the video stream
   somewhere in memory and then send it (*forward*) to web browser? Could you describe how  should this work in more deeply?

What should I start with? Thank you

Comment: your requisite is to stream live the content of android camera to any desktop browser ...if this is then you will need to create a socket connection which will sent continuous stream and at other end the decoder will be decoding the frame .. now you can search about socket programming

Comment: With socket programming I guess I wouldnt be able to develop subapplication on web server just by php because its execution time is limited to 30 seconds. It sounds logically to use sockets, but, is there way to get around? I would prefer not to develop whole server subapplication on my own if possible.
If I would do it all on my own, I would also need to take care of listening on port, sending html response to web browser and other things that can `Apache` do

Answer (score 1):

For this, you will have to use RTSP(Real Time Streaming Protocol),try learning this and for details you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186950/video-streaming-using-rtsp-android)